# create a datetime instance of a particular format

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

By default when we create a datetime instance, the format includes microseconds.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 19, 16, 13, 7, 415321)
```

If I don't want the microseconds part in the instance then I do this,

```
>>> str = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> new_dt = datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

So my question here is that is there any way where we can specify the format in which we want the datetime instance to be created rather than converting it to formatted string we want and then converting back to datetime instance.

Comment: Why don't you want milliseconds? You won't even know they're there if you print it out as you've shown with `strftime`

Comment: An instance of `datetime` is not 'formatted'. It is an object that has a millisecond component. Are you asking us to help you remove that component? Why do you need it removed? Why not just set it to `0` (`dt.replace(microsecond=0)`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'm not asking as to how to remove that component. I was just curious to know if there is a way to create an instance of datetime in the desired format.

Comment: @kunal: stop using the term 'format'. That only applies to formatting string output, you don't have a string here.

Comment: @kunal: your `.strftime()`, `.strptime()` dance does exactly the same thing as what my answer does, produce a new `datetime` instance, only with `microsecond=0` set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `datetime` object *has no format*. It is not created in any specific format, it is just an instance of a class. That instance has attributes, and those attributes have values.

If you need to have an instance that represents a time with the `microsecond` attribute set to `0`, just use the [`datetime.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to create a new instance from one with all the other attributes correct:

```
now = datetime.now()
now_without_ms = now.replace(microsecond=0)
```

However, if you wanted to format a `datetime` object for printing, then just format it without the microseconds component:

```
print(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

You don't *have* to use the microsecond attribute anywhere.

Comment: To note: a `datetime` object with a `millisecond` value of `0` still *has a millisecond property*, its value just happens to be `0`. You can't "remove" it entirely. :)

Comment: @deceze: *If you need to have an instance that represents a time with the millisecond attribute set to 0*.

Comment: @deceze: and the whole `strftime()`, `strptime()` dance does the same thing, produce a new `datetime` instance with `millisecond=0`.